# How can we dynamically populate quick replies of facebook messenger from a JSON object?

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger, chatbot

I really liked the Facebook quick replies feature which helps us guide the conversation with the user. 
My context is I am building a form fill bot. There are a few questions a user is asked before he is redirected to the appropriate page. The questions and their options come as a JSON object.
I would like to make the question as a text message and the options as quick replies. This would greatly help the user quickly answer the few questions and get the form filled.
I am stuck at the point where I need to populate the quick replies options with the questions' options.
I am using Microsoft Bot builder framework to build the bot

Answer (score 1):

Channel's specific features (such as the Quick Replies from Facebook) are supported through the [ChannelData](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html) (C#) / [sourceEvent](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/calling-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iconversation.html#sourceevent) (Node) fields. So you need to send the specific info through it so Facebook can understand it and react accordingly.

[Here](http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/15/sending-facebooks-quick-replies-using-microsoft-bot-framework/) is a quick example showing how to send Facebook's Quick Replies.

```
var channelData = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            quick_replies = new dynamic[]
            {
                new
                {
                    content_type = "text",
                    title = "Blue",
                    payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_BLUE",
                    image_url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developperss/PNG/Blue%20Ball.png"
                },
                new
                {
                    content_type = "text",
                    title = "Green",
                    payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_GREEN",
                    image_url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developperss/PNG/Green%20Ball.png"
                },
                new
                {
                    content_type = "text",
                    title = "Red",
                    payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_RED",
                }
            }
        });

        reply.ChannelData = channelData;
```

You can also find more details about how to use new Facebook's features with BotFramework in this [blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2016/09/15/facebook-messenger-updates/).

Please note that in the particular case of Quick Replies, the BotFramework team is adding support to them in the library. The [commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/cebcc423d1d11e7c80a6936a4d962b2fbbe400f9) is still in the develop branch; so it's not yet public (you can still build the library and reference to that instead of the public NuGet)

Comment: Thank Ezequiel Jadib. I missed mentioning one more hurdle. The number of options are varying i.e., some questions have 3 options while some have 6.

Comment: Thanks Ani110591. I don't understand what's the issue with that though. Quick Replies supports up to 10 buttons I think

Comment: so the link you gave mentions a Helper Classes, where a pre defined payload can be populated. But I need to make a dynamic set of options  which vary anywhere between 3 to 6 options depending on the number of options that come as a response for pinging the questions API.

Comment: The helper classes are just to avoid using dynamic objects; for every question you have, you will need to create different 'quick replies' that means, 3 or 6 options. Apologize if I missing something here; but the flow that I imagine is: pinging the questions API gives me 3 options, then I would do a for to create the quick replies. If it gives me 6; perfect, I will do the same